How to dynamically change language using Iubenda with React hooks
I have a React application with a custom hook that initialise iubenda with a default lang.
// App.tsx
function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState('it');
  useIubendaPolicy(lang);

  return (
    <>
      <select defaultValue="it" onChange={(e) => setLang(e.target.value)}>
        <option>en</option>
        <option>it</option>
      </select>
    </>
  );
}

// useIubendaPolicy.tsx
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// Define a type for supported languages
type Language = 'en' | 'it';

// Define a mapping from language to environment variable keys
const policyUrls: Record<Language, string | undefined> = {
  en: xxxxxxxxx,
  it: xxxxxxxxx,
};

const appendScript = (src: string) => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = src;
  script.charset = 'UTF-8';
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};

export const useIubendaPolicy = (lang: Language) => {
  const iubendaSiteId = xxxxxxxxx;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!lang || !iubendaSiteId) return;

    const policyValue = policyUrls[lang];

    (window as any)._iub = (window as any)._iub || [];
    // Mandatory property access
    (window as any)._iub.csConfiguration = {
      askConsentAtCookiePolicyUpdate: true,
      enableFadp: true,
      fadpApplies: true,
      floatingPreferencesButtonDisplay: 'bottom-right',
      perPurposeConsent: true,
      siteId: iubendaSiteId, // siteId is unique for all langs
      whitelabel: false,
      cookiePolicyId: policyValue,
      lang: lang,
      banner: {
        acceptButtonDisplay: true,
        closeButtonDisplay: false,
        customizeButtonDisplay: true,
        explicitWithdrawal: true,
        listPurposes: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        rejectButtonDisplay: true,
        showTitle: false,
      },
    };

    const iubendaAutoblocking = `https://cs.iubenda.com/autoblocking/${iubendaSiteId}.js`;
    const iubendaCs = 'https://cdn.iubenda.com/cs/iubenda_cs.js';

    appendScript(iubendaAutoblocking);
    appendScript(iubendaCs);
  }, [lang]);
};

During navigation (ignoring wether user accepted or not the cookies and ignoring any route lang logic or browser history), user can change language using the dedicated dropdown, so I want iubenda contents to be in the new selected language.
However, my approach does not work, when I change language new iubenda scripts are appended to the  element but the cookie policy modal still contains the previous language set (when code is inspected the iubenda button, for example, did not update according the new configuration).
I did try as well with a cleanup of any previous iubenda script and/or button html element
    return () => {
      document.body.querySelectorAll('script[src*="iubenda"]').forEach((script) => {
        document?.body?.removeChild(script);
      });
    };

But this does not seems to work either, so I had a look on their support page but could not find any useful method to relaunch/replaced their scripts.
I have a public reproduction code if needed, any help is appreciated.
